# Connecting a Wireless Network programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement where the client needs to automatically connect to a active wireless network based on his location.

The requirement is such that whenever a hotspot is available (in the absence of the user’s home network), the client will automatically connect to a wireless network present in that location and everything in that app (Weather Information etc) should work in the presence of this active internet connection
While in presence of a secure Home network (the user’s own hub), it should automatically demote the network selected previously from the wireless networks list, thus enabling the device to automatically connect to the secure Home network

Is there any api in iPhone SDK where we can implement this functionality? If yes, are these api private or public? Can we have access to these api for development?

Comment: Is this for an app store app? There's no public APIs that let you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi setup is handled by Apple80211.framework. That's a private API. You cannot use it for apps you want to distribute or contract work.

If you need this functionality in iOS, you should file an enhancement request at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: OK! then is it possible to atleast detect the wi-fi network a user is connected to?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library