# Reachability Help - WiFi Detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reachability

I have imported Reachability into my application, and I have a couple of how-to questions for you all. Let me explain my application and other tools first.

This application communicates with two things AT THE SAME TIME, an ad-hoc network, and the internet through 3G. Note: The ad-hoc network IS NOT connected to the internet. This works perfectly - it's already implemented and tests out wonderfully.

With that being said, I want to implement Reachability to detect a two things.

1) Is the user connected to a wifi ad-hoc network? (Even better, if possible, is to detect if it is connected to the wifi ad-hoc network with a prefix of WXYZ. For example, if there are two networks listed, one called Linksys and the other called WXYZ-Testing_Platform, it knows whether or not it is connected to WXYZ).

2) Can the user connect to the internet through 3G (or 2G, etc) and access our server?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT TO INCLUDE ANSWER FOR FUTURE LOOKERS:**

**For 1), my code looks like this:**

```
.h
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h> //for checking wifi network prefix

.m
- (BOOL) connectedToWifi
{

    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    // Get the dictionary containing the captive network infomation
    CFDictionaryRef captiveNtwrkDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));

    NSLog(@"Information of the network we're connected to: %@", captiveNtwrkDict);

    NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*) captiveNtwrkDict;
    NSString* ssid = [dict objectForKey:@"SSID"];

    if ([ssid rangeOfString:@"WXYZ"].location == NSNotFound || ssid == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And for 2)**, I imported Reachability and have it using this method whenever I go to connect to the server... NOTE:replace http://www.google.com with the server information

```
-(void) checkIfCanReachServer
{
UIAlertView *errorView;
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];


    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                     initWithTitle: @"Network Error" 
                     message: @"Cannot connect to the server." 
                     delegate: self 
                     cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];  
        [errorView show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reachability only lets you know if the device can send data packets **out** successfully. So
 for 1) you should refer to [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library). For 2) you will use Reachability only to check for an internet connection then you would need to use `NSURLConnection` or other network library to make sure you can reach your server.