# Select a WiFi network

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, wifi

I'm not sure if this is at all possible or not.

A client of our company would like to have the following:

- The client is a large retailer and has many shops.
- Each shop has a dedicated WLan
- When a customer enters a shop and the App is running it should recognize the network and connect to it.
- The customer can then use certain web services which are only available on this dedicated WLan.

The App is written in Monotouch on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like what [CaptiveNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) offers. The bindings for this are available in recent versions of MonoTouch (5.2+).

**UPDATE**: I updated the answer to [MonoTouch WIFI SSID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666397/monotouch-wifi-ssid) to show how to use CaptiveNetwork (a single call) from MonoTouch (but it's a bit different, subset, from what you're looking to do with the API).

Comment: Yep, looks like what i need. Are there any examples available? What do I need to reference the assebly? I constantly get EntryPointNotFoundException. I did the DllImport but it very well possible I generate a signature that can not be found. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is not something very commonly used AFAIK so there are no C# sample (that I know of). OTOH the API is very small/simple and MonoTouch 5.2+ has a `CaptiveNetwork` class under the `MonoTouch.SystemConfiguration` namespace (so you should not need your own `[DllImport]` declarations, see: http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=C%3AMonoTouch.SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

Comment: Yes I know I need my own. And I already found the documentation on the subject. But I have no clue what to declare. There are variables in there I can't find anywhere and they are not documented.

Comment: I've tried this too with the same result
MonoTouch.SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork.SetSupportedSSIDs(new string[] { "MyNet" });
System.EntyPointNotFoundException
Message: CNSetSupportedSSIDs

Comment: You misread me :) *so you should* **not** *need your own* `[DllImport]` means **everything** is already provided in MonoTouch, including the constants. `EntryPointNotFoundException` should **only** occurs on the simulator (since this API works only on devices).

Comment: Aha, ok, yes I misread. Thanks, I'll try it out on the device.