# WiFi possibilities on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, wifi

Is it possible on iPhone to create a data connection by specifying the SSID of the network?

Is it possible from application to check the signal/availability of the network with specified SSID?

Regards,
STeN

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library

Comment: However, signal strength cannot be fetched with the above method.

Comment: But he want's to connect to a network with certain SSID, not to get the SSID of the network iPhone is connected to. The answer is sadly: no, not using public API-s.

Comment: Hi Shivan - but this only tells me the SSID of the network I am connected to isn't it? Can I (in the case the used SSID of network I am connected to is different from the one I want to use) also force the phone to use the different WiFi network by specifying its SSID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is sadly **not possible without the usage of private (undocumented) API-s**.
Hopefully Apple will provide this kind of functionality (with users permition) though i don't think this is bound to happen soon.

If you want to research this topic further the first place to check would be [iphone-wireless](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) - the home of **Stumbler** which shows a nice usage of `MobileApple80211`.

Comment: Hi, but with Apple80211Functions we will be most likely forbidden on App Store, isn't it?

Comment: @STeN: yes - what you're looking for is not possible without use of private API-s. And using private API-s will get your app rejected for sure.

Comment: Thanks - that's all I need to know.