# How to get the connected wifi network name

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I have build hybrid application for IPAD, using cordova.
I need to get the name of connected current wifi network.
I have gone through couple of plugins of cordova which couldn't help me out.
Can anyone let me know how to achieve this by cordova plugin or javascript plugin.

Comment: You can try use this plugin https://github.com/HondaDai/PhoneGap-WifiInfoPlugin

Comment: Some links that could help :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5198968/8472539 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43543510/8472539

Answer (score 1):

You can use [plugin wifiWizard](https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard) for this. Plugin can be used as follows to get current ssid information.

```
function ssidHandler(s) {
    alert("Current SSID"+s);
}

function fail(e) {
    alert("Failed"+e);
}

function getCurrentSSID() {
    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);
}
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182536/how-can-i-get-wifi-network-information-ssid-in-a-phonegap-app) for more details