# How can I get WiFi Network information (SSID) in a Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am making a Phonegap app. My requirement is to show different views to users depending on whether they are using a home network or a public network. Is there any plugin or any other way that can help to get the connected network information. (Network SSID).

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is this [plugin](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard) for ***Android and iOS*** :

```
cordova plugin add wifiwizard
```

If you want to get the current SSID of the network you are connected to:

```
function ssidHandler(s) {
    alert("Current SSID"+s);
}

function fail(e) {
    alert("Failed"+e);
}

function getCurrentSSID() {
    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);
}
```

If you want to **get the list of SSID** you have *configured before* :

```
function listHandler(a) {
    alert(a);
}

function getWifiList() {
   WifiWizard.listNetworks(listHandler, fail);
}
```

If you want to return a complete scan result :

```
function listHandler2(a) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(a));
}

function getScanResult() {
    WifiWizard.getScanResults(listHandler2, fail);
 }
```

To test:

```
<button onclick="getCurrentSSID()">Get Current SSID</button> 
<button onclick="getWifiList()">Get configured SSID list</button> 
<button onclick="getScanResult()">Get Scan result</button>
```

Please see what you exactly need to get work from the list of the functions that the link I provided is offering and if you are encountering issues, reply.

Comment: Yeah, let us know. I'm interested in this too.

Comment: iOS is supported by WifiWizard

Comment: This should be in the documentation :/

Comment: Based on documentation they mentioned if app is using other apis than `GetCurrentSSID`(for example `GetScanResult` or `listNetworks`) apple will reject the app, any body has gone that far?

Comment: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard

Comment: Updated to "cordova plugin add wifiwizard"

Comment: For most recent patches and pull requests, check *WifiWizard2* here: https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2

Comment: WifiWizard2 is no longer supported and does not work with Android 11+ or iOS 14.5+

Answer (score 6):

While **`WifiWizard`** is great, it seems that it's no longer being maintained on GitHub.

As a replacement, you can use **[`WifiWizard2`](https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2)** which is under active development, as it supports the same methods:

```sh
cordova plugin add https://github.com/tripflex/WifiWizard2.git
```

```js
WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID(success, fail)
WifiWizard2.getConnectedBSSID(success, fail)
WifiWizard2.scan([options], success, fail)
```

WifiWizard2 seems to also support both Android and iOS.

---

However, if like me you also need to use the device's *Hotspot* or *Wifi Tethering* with Cordova, I recommend the [`cordova-hotspot-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-hotspot) package instead.  The project is unfortunately **discontinued**; but for older Android API levels, it still seems to work.

This plugin supports a myriad of methods, full list available [here](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-hotspot-plugin/blob/develop/PLUGIN_USAGE.MD#cordovapluginshotspot--object).

Comment: Thanks for this, 1st two options work, however the scan one gives [] back. Do you have an idea why? Using latest version of the plugin on Android device.

Comment: Just to let anyone know, if you get an empty [] in a newer version of Android, it's because you need to give Location permission to the app. Settings >> Apps >> theApp >> Permissions >> Location

Comment: I've been trying for several times to make this work with this code but it's not working:

WifiWizard2.scan(function(response) {
‎    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
‎}); Woud you mind helping please? @xxxxxxxxxxxxx I'm trying to get a list of available networks

Comment: WifiWizard2 is no longer supported and does not work with Android 11+ or iOS 14.5+