# Error while getting WiFi Network information (SSID) in phonegap App using com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

```
function ssidHandler(s){
    alert("Current SSID"+s);
}
function fail(e){
    alert("Failed"+e);
}

    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);
```

I tried this, but I am being always passed to error method. And alert message prints "

> Incorrect action parameter : getConnectedSSID"

I want to only use getConnectedSSID. apart from adding above code added

in my config.xml and built it on phonegap build.

and added WifiWizard.js from latest github repo

Please advice ...

github repo : 
https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard

This is question based on 
[How can I get WiFi Network information (SSID) in a Phonegap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182536/how-can-i-get-wifi-network-information-ssid-in-phonegap-app/32617228)

I initially posted the question there in answers section and it was deleted so posting as new question.

Comment: Phonegap plugin questions should go to the developer of that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved, 
source needed to be updated to npm and only then version 0.2.9 would work.
otherwise I was using 0.1.0

sample below

```
<gap:plugin name="com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard" source="npm" version="0.2.9"/>
```

for anyone's future reference !!!