# wifi configuration and wifi validation in wifiwizard cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, wifi

I'm trying to imply some functions in my WifiApp to **enable** the wifi once the app is **started**. So I wrote a function **startWifi()** and I'm getting the error message first "There is no wifi connection" after then my wifi is not getting enabled. I'm using wifiWizard plugin.

Here is my program
**WifiService.js**

```
function startWifi(e){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
        WifiWizard.setWifiEnabled(e, win_wifi, fail_wifi);  
        }, 500);
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.startWifi = function(enabled){
        WifiService.startWifi(enabled);
        alert("StartWifi");
    }
```

And please tell me how to write validation to connect to the wifi after scanning the wifi networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample code I wrote after creating a bare-bone cordova project and adding wifiwizard plugin, to check whether wifi is enabled in the device and to enable the same if it is disabled.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>            
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Wifi Wizard</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <br>        
        <br>
        Start Wifi <input type="button" value="wifi" name="Wifi" id="wifi"/>     <br>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {      
     $('#wifi').click( function() 
        {   
            try {               
                WifiWizard.isWifiEnabled(win, fail);
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert("Plugin Error - " + err.message);
            }

        }); 

    function win(e) {
        if(e) {
            alert("Wifi enabled already");
        }
        else {
            WifiWizard.setWifiEnabled(true, winEnable, failEnable);
        }

    }

    function fail(e) {
        alert("Error checking Wifi status");
    }

    function winEnable(e) {
        alert("Wifi enabled successfully");
    }

    function failEnable(e) {
        alert("Error enabling Wifi ");
    }
}
```

Please ensure to include jquery library file in your html. You can also check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182536/how-can-i-get-wifi-network-information-ssid-in-phonegap-app) to get more info on performing wifi scan using the plugin.

Have tested the same in Android 6 device and it works fine.

Comment: @RSN Once you get the list of SSIDs as per the link i mentioned, you can connect to any particular SSID using "WifiWizard.connectNetwork(SSID, win, fail);"

Comment: @RSN Have not tried it. But should work fine as its a plain javascript.

Comment: instead of wifi enabled already, can i try to disable the wifi using the code wifiwizard.setWifiEnabled(false), whether it works if i try

Comment: @RSN Should work perfectly fine.. "WifiWizard.setWifiEnabled(false, win, fail);"

Comment: thanks, so wifiwizard.connectNetwork how does it work, whether it validates the network by itself(password or any key press) or we have to write it manually.

Comment: @RSN you may have to try it out once. As far as i looked at the android source code of the plugin, i dont see any password validation. So it may work just with SSID prompting you to key in password. Not sure though. But could see password attribute in add network.

Comment: @RSN I feel you need not have to delete you comments for the benefit of others. Also good to see a BE student enthusiastic in coding.

Comment: im sorry its actually asking me to continue conversation in chat, thats why I did. And some wifi will be password protected. so when we try to connect  I have to do a prompt window to accept the password right! and what is the mistake in my code above angularjs, I too wrote the code to autostart the wifi after 500ms, why didn't work?

Comment: And in your code, you haven't mentioned about the wifi list which is the scan list

Comment: @RSN I feel chat would be a better option. Anyways the code i wrote was just for wifi check and enabling it. You should invoke this code inside deviceready event listener

Comment: it says not enough reputation to chat,

Comment: @RSN Oh i m sorry about that. But ensure that you have added cordova.js file in your html and invoking plugin code inside deviceready event listener

Comment: this event listener or the deviceready and the click function, how can i do that using angularjs, bcos my boss needs in angular+ionic

Comment: @RSN If its Ionic, just ensure to call this plugin code inside platform.ready function.

Comment: im sorry where will i find this platform.ready function? is it possible for u to send a mail for me regarding this, because it will not allow me after sometime to chat here, whether i can i share my email address here

Comment: @RSN You can share your's and delete it later once i have noted it

Comment: @RSN  Noted the details