# get ssid from access point in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, access-point, bssid

I want to get some uniqe information from access points such as mac address (bssid). I try this code, but it is only works when I connect a network..

```
- (id)fetchSSIDInfo
{
NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
id info = nil;
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
    info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
    if (info && [info count]) {
        break;
    }
    [info release];
}
[ifs release];
return [info autorelease];
}
```

How can I get bssid from access points around me even if I am not connected, is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5198968/1992125

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. And the answer is no.

You only can get the data of the connection you have.
You may use some private library, but it won t be approved by Apple.

Comment: This is not true. There are approved apps that not only get mac but other devices connected to the same network, and other ssids in the area