# iPhone netword SSID

Tags: iphone, xcode, error-handling

I am having issues implementing the code from the answer on this question: [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library)

I have xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.1.

```
 #import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

- (id)fetchSSIDInfo
{
    NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
    id info = nil;
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
        info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
        if (info && [info count]) {
            break;
        }
        [info release];
    }
    [ifs release];
    return [info autorelease];
}
```

I get the following errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add CFNetwork.framework to your project.

You can do it by selecting Targets > Summary> Linked Framework and Libraries.

Comment: I added it but I still have the 3 errors.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: try cleaning the project, re-build it, quit xcode and start again. sometimes it helps :)

Comment: It requires the SystemConfiguration framework also.  Then it worked :D