# Issues in using CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I am using the below code to retrieve the SSID of the WiFi network the iPod is connected.

```
NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
id info = nil;
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
    info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
    if (info && [info count]) {
        break;
    }
    [info release];
}
```

Sometimes this code is not returning the proper SSID of the network my device is connected.Any pointers on why the SSID is not retrieved correctly? Does CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo package dependent on the iOS version of the device?

Thanks.

Comment: I am running the code on an iOS 5.1 device.

Comment: Try the solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712535/how-do-i-use-captivenetwork-to-get-the-current-wifi-hotspot-name

Comment: Try the solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712535/how-do-i-use-captivenetwork-to-get-the-current-wifi-hotspot-name

Answer (score 6):

1. add SystemConfiguration.framework to project.
2. `import < SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h >`
3. ```
   CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
   CFStringRef interfaceName = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0);
   CFDictionaryRef captiveNtwrkDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interfaceName);
   NSDictionary *dict = ( NSDictionary*) captiveNtwrkDict;
   NSString* ssid = [dict objectForKey:@"SSID"];
   NSLog(@"%s ssid : %@",__FUNCTION__, [ssid description]);
   ```
4. For **iOS 12** and later, you must enable it from capabilities.

> Important
>   To use this function in iOS 12 and later, enable the Access WiFi Information capability for your app in Xcode. When you enable this capability, Xcode automatically adds the Access WiFi Information entitlement to your entitlements file and App ID. [Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo** is available only in **iOS 4.1** and later.

For more info ,please look at the [developer.apple SystemConfiguration Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html)

you can check the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195717/detect-the-name-of-wireless-network/13195734#13195734)