# How can i get list of available WiFi network using CaptiveNetwork

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, wifi

I want to get all the WiFi networks available in a region and their SSID and SSIDDATA value.
Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library) I am able to get the SSID and SSIDDATA value for the WiFi network that I am using. But the problem is how to get the SSID and SSIDDATA of all the WiFi network available even if I am not connected to one. I do not want to do it using the private API like in case of stumbler as it will be rejected by AppStore. Please advice.

Comment: people, its a humble request, please give reason along for the down vote..

Comment: Nope. It is not possible without using private APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't get them without using private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be able to through Apple's [SystemConfiguration API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration).

This code segment from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715055/how-to-get-available-wifi-network-name-in-ios-using-swift) might be useful:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

class FirstView: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ssid = self.getWiFiName()
        print("SSID: \(ssid)")
    }

    func getWiFiName() -> String? {
        var ssid: String?
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                    ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return ssid
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return only current connected wifi information. The question is all available wifi networks and not connected. First of all, Try to understand the question before writing any answer.