# Is there any way to get ssid of connected wifi in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking, capability

I want the information about the wifi with which my iPhone is connected. I have already added `Access WiFi Information`, `Hotspot Configuration` and `Network Extension` under `Signing & Capabilities` also Included UIBackgroundModes array containing `network-authentication` in the application `Info.plist.`

After all this, I also tried the below solution but always got empty or null as wifi SSID.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022195/11724588
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32767659/11724588
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5198968/11724588

**Code:**

```
func getInterfaces() -> Bool {
        guard let unwrappedCFArrayInterfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() else {
            print("this must be a simulator, no interfaces found")
            return false
        }
        guard let swiftInterfaces = (unwrappedCFArrayInterfaces as NSArray) as? [String] else {
            print("System error: did not come back as array of Strings")
            return false
        }
        for interface in swiftInterfaces {
            print("Looking up SSID info for \(interface)") // en0
         guard let unwrappedCFDictionaryForInterface = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) else {
                print("System error: \(interface) has no information")
                return false
            }
            guard let SSIDDict = (unwrappedCFDictionaryForInterface as NSDictionary) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("System error: interface information is not a string-keyed dictionary")
                return false
            }
            for d in SSIDDict.keys {
                print("\(d): \(SSIDDict[d]!)")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**Output logs:**

```
Looking up SSID info for en0
2020-02-25 14:22:53.640018+0530 Runner[422:22122] [] nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request
System error: en0 has no information
```

Comment: In iOS 13 you also need location permission

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes after adding location permission now I got SSID of network with which I am connected. Please post your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any way to get all available wifi list in the network in iOS swift? Because I have to connect my IOT device with One of that network.

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible for an app to obtain all available WiFi network names.