# Capture Wi-Fi network changing event in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

Is there any way to capture the event occurs when a user connects to a particular WiFi network in iOS app. It is fine even if this can be achieved using any private library which doesn't require super user privileges (jail break). I just want to capture the changing event of the  connected SSID.

Comment: Maybe with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library/7041017#7041017

Comment: This is to get the currently connected Wi-Fi SSID. I need to capture the event where user connects to a Wi-Fi network or change the currently connected Wi-FI network to some other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend simply using what Larme posted, and setting up an NSTimer to check every second or so, what the SSID of your current network is, if you detect a change, simply do whatever you need to do. Keep in mind, changing WiFi networks is not something that happens instantaneously, so having a 1 second resolution is not bad

**In `applicationDidFinishLoading`**

```
NSTimer *ssidTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fetchSSIDInfo) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**In AppDelegate**

```
- (id)fetchSSIDInfo {
     NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
     NSLog(@"Supported interfaces: %@", ifs);
     id info = nil;
     NSString *ifnam = @"";
     for (ifnam in ifs) {
         info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);
         NSLog(@"%@ => %@", ifnam, info);
         if (info && [info count]) { break; }
     }
     if ([info count] >= 1 && [ifnam caseInsensitiveCompare:prevSSID] !=  NSOrderedSame) {
          // Trigger some event
          prevSSID = ifnam;
     }

     return info;
}
```

Something like that. I can not check if code is typo free as I am not in front of a mac, but it should not be too different

Comment: Yes that is how I have done it already. I just wanted to check whether is there any method of doing this. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Not that I know of. There is probably some private method that Apple can use, but if you use it, you will get rejected. But writing your own is not too complicated.

Comment: This is documented https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo

Comment: What's wrong with using NetworkReachability API instead of timer? I guess Reachability is much more accurate and reliable..

Comment: @Andy I am not sure if NetworkReachability can tell whether or not a different network SSID was encountered. Plus, the method I posted is what I knew would work at the time. Plus, a one second resolution is still pretty accurate

Comment: `ifnam` is the interface name, not the SSID, so would not change when the Wi-Fi network changes

Comment: Also, `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` no longer returns SSID/BSSID information on iOS 13+ if the app does not have location permission. Is there any way to get it in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch details from your wifi connection:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getConnectionDetails
{
    NSDictionary *connectionDetails = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    if (myArray) {
        CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
        connectionDetails = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)myDict;
    }
    return connectionDetails;
}
```

And then if check `[connectionDetails valueForKey:@"BSSID"]` you will get BSSID.

Also please note that you must to import `#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>`

Comment: `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` no longer returns SSID/BSSID information on iOS 13+ if the app does not have location permission. Is there any way to get it in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You want [SystemConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration?language=objc), which has facilities for seeing notifications on all sorts of networking changes. In particular you'll want to use [SCDynamicStoreSetNotificationKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1437820-scdynamicstoresetnotificationkey?language=objc) to listen for changes to the devices and [SCNetworkConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkconfiguration?language=objc) to get information about the available interfaces.

Comment: I couldn't even find documentation on what you call "notifications on all sorts of networking changes". If you do could you please point out the documentation on how to detect the wi-fi change?