# Private Library SSID info for IOS?

Tags: ios, ios6, ssid, wifi

I am looking for an IOS enterprise programmers help/assistance:

I am looking to get the list of SSIDs and Signal strength if possible from an iPhone running IOS6, but I keep hitting roadblocks.   I know I have to use a private library - but I have no idea of where I can find it, and/or how to use it.

I have looked at the documentation at [iPhone wireless project](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) - but it does not look like that works anymore.

This is an APP that I don't plan on distributing to the public.   So I don't mind using private libraries if I know where they are and how to use them properly.  This is simply a prototype for a bigger project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Ryan

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library

Answer (score 0):

Current thinking is not to use private libraries, but to use SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork, as described in this article: [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library)
The method is official and well documented by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html

However, for an internal App, you can take a look at MobileApple80211 library created by the iPhone Wireless project: https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/

Comment: Add a short summary of the article you're linking to. The link it self is not enough.