# Swift: How do you use an Objective-C function from a linked library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**Background**

I'm new to iOS development and playing with Swift for the sake of learning.  As a small challenge, I'm trying to get the SSID of network to which a device is currently connected.

This is well-covered ground on Stack using Objective-C:  [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library), for example ... but the Objective-C / Swift dance is causing me some conceptual challenges.

Specifically, the suggested solution (discussed in the above-linked post) is to call the function `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo()` -- but, according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo), this function is not available in Swift.

**So far**

I've included (I think correctly) `SystemConfiguration.framework` by adding it to the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** of the project.  I've also brought it into the View Controller using `import SystemConfiguration`.

**Questions**

1. Do I need to *also* use `import SystemConfiguration`, or is that already done due to including the framework with my project?
2. Is there another / better way to include the `SystemConfiguration` library?
3. **The big one**: How, once the required library is imported, do you call the Objective-C function from the library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's interoperability book (from [Understanding the Swift Import Process](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0)):

> Any Objective-C framework (or C library) that’s accessible as a module
>   can be imported directly into Swift. This includes all of the
>   Objective-C system frameworks—such as Foundation, UIKit, and
>   SpriteKit—as well as common C libraries supplied with the system.

Regarding your specific questions:

1. The opposite is the case: you do not need to manually include Apple's frameworks. Xcode will automatically make them available to you given a valid `import` statement (such as `import SystemConfiguration` in your case), even – or rather: especially – in a playground!
2. ditto...
3. Given the above import statement, `SystemConfiguration` is indeed imported since you can call its functions (e.g. `SCCopyLastError() // --> __NSCFError`) and access its constants (e.g. `kCFErrorDomainSystemConfiguration // --> com.apple.SystemConfiguration`). Unfortunately, `CaptiveNetwork` does not seem to be imported with it (e.g. `CNCopySupportedInterfaces() // --> Use of unresolved identifier`).

You should be able, however, to use this framework on the Objective C side and simply call your own wrapper functions from Swift. You just need to remember to include them among the imports listed in your bridging header (see [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76) for more about bridging headers).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not directly answering your question, but it's an answer to your problem.
You can do everything in swift in your case.

After importing the library,

`import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork`

You can immediately call:

`CNCopySupportedInterfaces()`

and it will work.
Confirmed in Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: The only catch is that autocomplete still does not show anything when I type "CN" and hit Ctrl+Space. Don't be deceived by that - full word "CNCopySupportedInterfaces" will work!

Comment: Do you know who owns the object?  According to documentation which covers only Objective C it's users responsibility to call CFRelease, however this function is not available in Swift.