# How Nest iOS App could get SSID list

Tags: ios, ssid

I have done a lot of search and find out that, without private api we can only get the SSID of the network your device is currently connected to, but I have tried Nest iOS App, this app could get the SSID list, why is that, did Nest use private api, why apple didn't reject Nest App.

Comment: Does this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040397/get-list-available-wireless-access-points and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library?lq=1 help?

Comment: I already read these post before, still, it is about getting the current connected wifi, what I'm asking is how to get the available/configured wifi list? such as Nest iOS App, it could get a wifi list, not only the current-connected wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how Nest App achieve this: first, nest app should connect to the AP of Nest device (which contains a wifi module, and, of course it could scan the available wifi), and then the nest device will send the wifi list to nest app.