# Detect if device is connected to a specific network(office wifi)

Tags: objective-c

I have an enterprise iOS app and I am trying to detect if the device running the app is connected to the office wifi.

I can't find relevant information and I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: try to access some internal server

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library