# IOS8 get available wifi list

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

I want to get list of Available wifi in my iphone range programticlly , this is posible ? I understand that apple allow this in ios 8 but not found any relavent docs...

Please help ! 
Thanks ...

Comment: There is a way to get connected wi-fi detail, not all, If you need then I can provide you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone get SSID without private library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library)