# how to get SSID scanned from the device in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ssid

I know we can get the current connected SSID
I'm tryin to get all the scanned SSID 
 is there a way to have a list of all scanned SSID in IOS ??

Comment: Without private API,you can not.

Comment: ah ok , and which private API should I use to do that ? :)

Comment: this is possible also without private lib.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library

Comment: thanks @DanielKrom , but this code just get the curren connected SSID , I wand to get all the connected SSID